# To what extent do children adapt to a language which is not their mother-tongue?

Tags: psycholinguistics, second-lang-acquisition

In following when talking about 'native speaker' I refer to what is considered as 'mother tongue' rather than reaching a level of fluency.
For the purpose of this question think of an average person who is not a prodigious infant who is talented in learning languages but also not being exceptionally incapable of learning languages.
Furthermore, it shouldn't be of interest if languages X and Y are related, say, German and Dutch, or if they are completely different, say, Spanish and Japanese.

As a native speaker of whichever language you are able to recognize other speakers as also being native. When someone learns a language as a second language he'll probably never reach the same level as those who speak that language as first language, even if they live in the foreign country for a long time. There'll (almost <sup>1</sup>) always be a few indicator which will distinguish them from native speakers. And I don't refer to accent or similar but only to the language skills and feel for a language, i.e. word-choice, grammar etc.

I was thinking of what would happen if a child is born in country X into a native family of the respective language but being raised in country Y by a family whose native language is Y.

Q1: Will this child ever 'perfectly' speak language Y and be recognized by other speakers of Y as native? Or does this child has an inborn ability to language X and, for that reason, will not be able to speak language Y good enough?

Q2: What would happen if this child will have instructions in their 'inborn' language? Will they easily learn their <strike>second</strike> 'inborn' language? Similar, what would happen if this person would move to country X after growing up. Will they be able to learn language X good enough to be recognized as a native speaker of X?

---

<sup>1</sup>The exception that proves the rule.

Comment: That depends almost entirely on the child. Some children adapt immediately with dazzling speed, while others never really seem comfortable, and a few fail to adapt well. While there is a great deal of similarity among people in the ways they learn their language, and the degree to which they command it unconsciously, people vary a great deal in the ways and degrees they adapt to non-native languages. There are simply too many variables to generalize. About the only generalization that one can rely on is: The earlier the better, and the more intensive, the better.

Comment: That depends one what age the child moves from Country X to Country Y. There is no inborn ability in a certain language just because the parents spoke it, it has to be acquired in the years after birth.

Answer (score 1):

In India almost all children speak more than one language, especially because languages change every hundred or so miles. I spoke Tamil at home and spoke Kannada outside when we moved to Karnataka. I was fluent in both. Most of my friends spoke Kannada at school (and play) but other languages at home, Telugu, Marati etc.